# show menu list inline in html

Tags: html, css

How can i show below select list inline.
Currently the lists are just stacking one over another.

```
       <div id="menuBar">



        <form>
            <select ng-model="selectOperation">
                <option value="showtable">View table data</option>
                <option value="inserttable">Insert table data</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <form ng-submit="formSubmit()">
                <select ng-model="textbox">
                    <option value="emp">EMP</option>
                    <option value="dept">DEPT</option>
                    <option value="bonus">BONUS</option>
                    <option value="salgrade">SALGRADE</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="OK">
        </form>

        </div>
```

example here
http://fiddle.jshell.net/p6Lgn7bg/

Comment: If you mean the *actual* `<select>` elements..you can't show the `option`s inline. You would need a JS replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
form {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

to your css. Alternatively, if you'd like to target just this form, use:

```
#menuBar form {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Your original code was close, you just have to target the form elements instead of the whole form.